# Copy relative data validation rules

Tags: excel

I'm sorry if I put this question in the wrong section, because it is not entirely focussed on programming. But I don't know where to put it else.

I have the following rule as data validation for a particular cell in Excel:

```
=INDIRECT($D$5)
```

I want to copy this data validation rule to other cells. However, when I copy/paste the cell, it literally pastes the value of the data validation instead of the relative data validation. So I want $D$5 to be $D$6, $D$7 etc. in other cells. I have tried Paste Special > Validation, but it didn't work. Maybe there is a script for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `$` signs.

Comment: Wow it worked! I thought that is never gonna work so I didn't even try it. Aren't the $'s meant for relative references? So it should work this way instead of the other way, right? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to look up relative and absolute references. `$` is for absolute references.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @doug-glancy comment and to make sure there is an answer for this question, **writing a formula as `=INDIRECT(D5)` does the job.**

In my case I set the formula and by drag and drop copying the cell formulas of new cells will automatically get updated.